# Search by company name using Azure map provider

Tags: azure-maps

Is there some way to search for an address by the name of a company/organization using Azure maps API?
I read the description of all azure maps search APIs, but I did not find such a possibility, which, for example, is available in Google maps APIs.

Answer (score -1):

The Fuzzy and POI search services can find the company for you and in the response the address is included.

Comment: No, Fuzzy and POI give poor results when searching for a company by the name

Comment: Have you tried to help the service narrow the search by setting the countrySet parameter, or if the user will be doing a local search, consider passing in their lat/lon so it will bring the most relevant that are near them to the top.

Comment: Can you provide an example request?

Comment: No, I did not search with the country set, but I think this is the not best way - force the user to also choose the country in which he wants to find a company.

Comment: You don't have to force the user to set the country, there are a lot of different ways to help give the search engine more context. If all you pass in is a business name, the whole world is searched. For performance, the most common results that are similar to your query will be returned. Note that with Google Maps have more context as they often already know where the user is, but that also causes issues for other scenarios. What you can do is grab the users IP address, use the Geolocation API to get there country and use that as the country set.

Comment: I can give an example comparing the two APIs: 
GetSeacrhFuzzy of the Azure provider and TextSearch of the Google provider. Google finds this company, Azure - no.
With the setted country in both APIs

Comment: https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?subscription-key=[subscription_key]&api-version=1.0&typeahead=true&limit=10&topLeft=56.703,-54.769&btmRight=34.188,74.707&minFuzzyLevel=1&maxFuzzyLevel=3&query=Abona&countrySet=DE
Result did not find for a company

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Abona&region=de&key=[subscription_key]
Result found

Comment: Looks like you are looking for "ABONA Deutschland GmbH", it appears that location isn't in the data set. Data related issues can be reported and tracked here: https://feedback.azuremaps.com/

Comment: I've submitted this location to be added. You can track the status here: https://feedback.azuremaps.com/status?id=6badbb0f-8f82-465b-8ff5-b8050a0b2c74